# my springboot application embered tomcat started is very slowly

Tags: java, tomcat, startup

[this is the startup log in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nd1vV.png)

```
21:20:45,691 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@28c97a5 - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point


  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::       (v2.1.12.RELEASE)

2021-01-06 21:20:46,346 [main] INFO  com.pingan.smartcity.scw.whapply.WhApplyApplication - Starting WhApplyApplication v1.0-SNAPSHOT on izxs801ql7o8q7dbxyv64jz with PID 11576 (/opt/data/app/h5/whapply-xm-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar started by root in /opt/data/app/h5)
2021-01-06 21:20:46,349 [main] DEBUG com.pingan.smartcity.scw.whapply.WhApplyApplication - Running with Spring Boot v2.1.12.RELEASE, Spring v5.1.13.RELEASE
2021-01-06 21:20:46,349 [main] INFO  com.pingan.smartcity.scw.whapply.WhApplyApplication - The following profiles are active: prod
2021-01-06 21:20:47,511 [main] WARN  org.mybatis.spring.mapper.ClassPathMapperScanner - No MyBatis mapper was found in '[com.pingan.smartcity.scw.whapply]' package. Please check your configuration.
2021-01-06 21:20:47,550 [main] INFO  org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate - Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode!
2021-01-06 21:20:47,552 [main] INFO  org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate - Bootstrapping Spring Data Redis repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2021-01-06 21:20:47,596 [main] INFO  org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate - Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 30ms. Found 0 Redis repository interfaces.
2021-01-06 21:20:48,110 [main] INFO  o.s.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker - Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f5a22d6c] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2021-01-06 21:36:15,587 [main] INFO  org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer - Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8899 (http)
2021-01-06 21:36:15,608 [main] INFO  org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol - Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8899"]
2021-01-06 21:36:15,622 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService - Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-01-06 21:36:15,622 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine - Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.30]
2021-01-06 21:36:15,710 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/] - Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-01-06 21:36:15,710 [main] INFO  org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 929305 ms
```

As shown in the picture above, It takes 10 minutes to start my springboot application, This is very abnormal, what's the problem '

Comment: we need more context and details to be able to help

Comment: What do you use in your spring boot application? Do you have any beans that need to wait for something or require computational power at creation?

Comment: I have added the log

Comment: The log is not sufficient on its own.

Comment: when i start my application in myself compute , that is very fast ,but when i run it in my production environment , It becomes abnormal

Comment: between 21:20:48,110  and  21:36:15,587, it cost almost 10 minutes ,why?